# Is it possible to explicitly instantiate a templated function that returns an unspecified type?

Tags: c++, c++20, explicit-instantiation

I'm trying to perform explicit instantiation of templated functions to improve accuracy of my code coverage results.  I know how to do this when the return type is known.  I can indirectly achieve the desired outcome through a definition of a wrapper function that returns `void`.  Is it possible to achieve the outcome without this additional function definition?

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
struct Gen {
    T operator()() const { return T{}; }
};
template <std::default_initializable T>
Gen<T> buildKnown() {
    return Gen<T>{};
}
template <std::default_initializable T>
std::invocable auto buildConstrained() {
    return Gen<T>{};
}
template <std::default_initializable T>
std::invocable auto buildInternal() /* -> decltype(??) */ {
    struct Local : Gen<T> {};
    return Local{};
}

// Perform explicit instantiation of each templated function.
template Gen<int> buildKnown<int>();        // works
template Gen<int> buildConstrained<int>();  // somewhat surprised this doesn't work.
template auto buildInternal<int>();         // not surprised this doesn't work

// Indirectly instantiate buildInternal through a wrapper function.
template <typename T> void buildInternalWrapper() { buildInternal<T>(); }
template void buildInternalWrapper<int>();
```

EDIT: Fixed type constraint (was originally `std::invocable<int>`) that makes the question more confusing.

Comment: `auto` in this case is basically an implicit template parameter.  You have to explicitly spell out every return type you want, so `N` types mean `N` instantiations.

Comment: @NathanOliver, if I understood what you meant, then I would expect the explicit instantiation of template Gen<int> buildConstrained<int>(); to compile.  That line fails with a compilation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, your deduced return type constraints are wrong. Consider for example this function template that you wrote:

```
template <std::default_initializable T>
std::invocable<T> auto buildConstrained() {
    return Gen<T>{};
}
```

What will happen if this is instantiated with `T` = `int`? It will become

```
std::invocable<int> auto buildConstrained() {
    return Gen<int>{};
}
```

The placeholder type specifier `std::invocable<int> auto` means that the type needs to be deduced, and, if we call this deduced type `U`, then the constraint `std::invocable<U, int>` must be satisfied. So this function definition is only well-formed if `std::invocable<Gen<int>, int>` is satisfied. But it's not; `Gen<int>` is invocable with 0 arguments, not with 1 `int` argument.

I'm guessing you meant:

```
template <std::default_initializable T>
std::invocable auto buildConstrained() {
    return Gen<T>{};
}
```

Having made such an amendment, we can now declare the explicit instantiation:

```
template std::invocable auto buildConstrained<int>();
```

An explicit instantiation of a function template that uses a placeholder type specifier must also use the same placeholder type specifier, not the deduced type.

Comment: Yeah.  I made a typo on the deduced return type constraints.  Appreciate your response in light of my error.